# WebExtenssions : How make a manifest

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I make my first chrome extenssion and i got an error
`Manifest version 2 is deprecated, and support will be removed in 2023. See https://developer.chrome.com/blog/mv2-transition/ for more details.`

But i don't know hwo can i configure a manifest-v3

this is my code

```json
// manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Text Saver",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Saves selected text to a document",
  "permissions": ["storage", "contextMenus"],
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you explain me how i have to configure it ?